# Get full file location in AHK called from WSL

Tags: sublimetext3, autohotkey, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have used `alias subl='"/mnt/c/Program Files/Sublime Text 3/subl.exe"'` and  `subl test.txt` to open a file in sublime text. This opens up sublime text on windows, with the full file path.

When I try `alias subl='"/mnt/c/Users/altar/Google Drive/Files/PC/Desktop/testasda.exe"'` and have a script with

```
f=%1%
MsgBox, %f%
```

Then calling `subl test.txt` will only display test.txt. How would I get the complete path to the file, like sublime text does?

Comment: It's unclear from your question, but Sublime may be inferring the full path to the file by knowing that `text.txt` is inside whatever the current directory is (or if you will, it's getting the same `test.txt` as your script, but it's adding the current directory and you are not. You may want to include a call to `pwd` in your script to capture the current directory (though there is more to how this works if the filename has a relative path like `../test.txt`).

Answer (score 0):

Rather than an alias try creating a file in /usr/bin called testasda (i assume /usr/bin is on your path in wsl). Then in the file put:

```
/mnt/c/Users/altar/Google\ Drive/Files/PC/Desktop/testasda.exe $(wslpath -w "$(pwd)/$1") &
```

This should open the second argument ($1) in the current path (pwd) using the application testasda.exe

[wslpath](https://github.com/laurent22/wslpath) is needed to convert from the wsl path to the dos path. This should be included in the wsl install ([link](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/WSL/releases/tag/17046))